# How to properly use Rselenium to wait for a page to load?

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

So I'm trying to scrape the name and location of various breweries in the US via this link:

https://www.brewersassociation.org/directories/breweries/

As you can see the HTML takes a second to load. This means that when I scrape the HTML code with Rselenium that it only loads half the page, here's the code that I'm running that should replicate for anyone with Rselenium,

```
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                                 port = 4445L,
                                 browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$setTimeout(type="page load")
remDr$navigate("https://www.brewersassociation.org/directories/breweries/?location=MI")

remDr$screenshot(display=TRUE)
```

However if you look at the screenshot only half of the page loads. I've tried set Timeout and a few other commands but they don't seem to allow the page to load correctly. Any advice or ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
library(RSelenium) 
driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"), port = 4567L)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.brewersassociation.org/directories/breweries/?location=MI")
#You can wait 3 seconds
Sys.sleep(3)
#Now you can scroll down all page and wait for the full page
scroll_d <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "css", value = "body")
#This will scroll the page but is not enough, but is a way to create an automatization. 
#If you scroll the page many times you are able to see all page.
scroll_d$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
#How? For example you can use the alphabet to monitor the list.
```

This answer is just a way/idea to solve the problem.